# Regex in proxy path

Tags: angular, proxy

Is it possible to add regex in proxy path?
I'm using Angular 15, and I would like to add to proxy every path with substring 'test', so eg 'test-dog', test-cat', 'test-something'.
Can I add it once, without having to list all the possibilities?

I was thinking something like:

```
{
  "/test-(.*)": {
    "target": "http://localhost:1845",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't have to use regex, this should be enough: `/test-*`